# Mac play not added to path

Tags: macos, command-line

I have installed the play framework using `typesafe-activator`. However, this does not appear on in PATH. Therefore, I can not use Play from the command line:

```
Octavians-MBP:exericsePS octavian$ play new app
-bash: play: command not found
```

If I try to install play using brew I get:

```
Octavians-MBP:exericsePS brew install play
Error: No available formula for play
Play 2.3 replaces the play command with activator:
  brew install typesafe-activator

You can read more about this change at:
  https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/Migration23
  https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/Highlights23
```

However, I can not install it with typesafe-activator either:

```
Octavians-MBP:exericsePS octavian$ brew install typesafe-activator
Warning: typesafe-activator-1.3.5 already installed
Warning: You are using OS X 10.11.
We do not provide support for this pre-release version.
You may encounter build failures or other breakage.
Octavians-MBP:exericsePS octavian$ play help
-bash: play: command not found
```

So how can I install Play such that it's visible from the command line?

Answer (score 1):

Just add path to the play installation to your `.bash_profile` file in the user root directory.

For example I have

```
export PATH="/usr/local/mysql/bin:/Users/currentuser/PlayProjects/activator:$PATH"
```

This discussion could help you as well:

https://superuser.com/questions/314852/how-to-install-the-play-framework-on-os-x